# Conditional AND statement based on results of COUNT()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting lost in a query's logic, and I need some help.  To start, I have a parent table `Campaigns`. Then, a child table `CampaignParks` that looks like this:

```
select * from CampaignParks
```

[image]

For business reasons I won't bore you with, we need to include Parks in the Campaign table even if they are not included in the Campaign.  To actually include them in the campaign, there is a flag for that. None, one, or multiple Parks might be set to Include In Campaign.

Ok.  Simple enough.  Now...

Given a @ParkID, I need to return all parent Campaigns where the ParkID is a match, but ONLY if one (or more) of the `IncludeInCampaign` flags for the campaign has been set. If no `IncludeInCampaign` flags for a given campaign have been set, then we just ignore the value of @Parks.  We don't care about it.

Examples:

- @ParkID = 11070.  We get back 4 & 1
- @ParkID = 11526.  We get back 1
- @ParkID = 26496.  We get back 1
- @ParkID = null.  We get back 4 & 1
- ParkID = 69.  We get back 1.

So, I *think* the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    sc.ContactID,
    cp.*
FROM
    Campaigns sc
    JOIN CampaignParks cp on sc.CampaignID = cp.CampaignID
WHERE 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CampaignParks cp2 WHERE cp2.CampaignID = sc.CampaignID AND cp2.IncludeInCampaign = 1) > 0 OR cp.ParkID = @ParkID)
```

But, this isn't getting me the right results.

(I need to take my daughter to gymnastics... I'll take a look at relies when I get back.  Thank you!!)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is close.  The major difference is the `AND` versus `OR` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT sc.ContactID, cp.*
FROM Campaigns c JOIN
     CampaignParks cp
     on sc.CampaignID = cp.CampaignID
WHERE cp.ParkId = @ParkId AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM CampaignParks cp2
              WHERE cp2.CampaignID = cp.CampaignID AND
                    cp2.IncludeInCampaign = 1
             );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I am still getting two rows (1 & 4) when @ParkID = 11526.